# jboss how to use localhost:8080/projectname without "projectname"?

Tags: java, networking, jboss

So, how to use `ip:8080/projectname/*` without `/projectname/`, just `ip:8080/`?

Already try to redirect all content, but it's not exactly what i need.

Comment: name your war ROOT.war?

Comment: no, in my case project name - education, so education.war

Comment: he means change your war name to ROOT.war

Comment: Yeah, i understand it, now going to try it.

Answer (score 1):

I've written some time ago a tutorial which describes how to deploy a Web application to the Root contexton AS 7. 
[How to deploy a Web application to JBoss root context](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7)

Hope it helps